# Android Studio, No se reciben notificaciones push cuando app esta cerrada o suspendida

Tags: android, firebase

tengo una aplicación que utiliza firebase para poder mandar notificaciones push
Lo que ocurre es que en mi código tengo varias condiciones de cuando el titulo sea una palabra especifica haga algo, solo que cuando la app esta cerrada o en segundo plano solo recibe la notificación predefinida y no accede a la condición que tengo, en cambio si esta abierta lo hace normalmente y me muestra una notificación dependiendo de lo que diga el titulo, les dejo el codigo donde tengo implementado

MiFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package com.exaple.eduardo.hola.firebase;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.exaple.eduardo.hola.BaseDeDatos;
import com.exaple.eduardo.hola.Frase_del_Dia;
import com.exaple.eduardo.hola.MainActivity;
import com.exaple.eduardo.hola.R;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;

public class MiFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){


        mostrarNotificacion(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getData());

    }


}

private void mostrarNotificacion(String title, String body, Map<String, String> data) {

    Uri sounduri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


    if (title.equals("Frase")){

        BaseDeDatos db2 = new BaseDeDatos(this, "db", null, 1);
        db2.openDataBase();
        final SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDataBase = db2.getWritableDatabase();
        int numero = (int) (Math.random() * 70) + 1;
        Cursor file = BaseDeDataBase.rawQuery("select frase from Frases where id="+ numero,null);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Frase_del_Dia.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("numero", numero);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        if (file.moveToFirst()){
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icov2)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContentTitle("Frase del dia")
                    .setContentText(file.getString(0))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(sounduri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
        BaseDeDataBase.close();

    }
    else {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icov2)
                .setTicker("Nuevo Mensaje")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sounduri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icov2"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".firebase.MiFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".firebase.MiFirebaseInstanceidService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".service.MusicService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MenuPrincipal" />
    <activity android:name=".Frase_del_Dia" />
    <activity android:name=".ProximamenteActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TeAmoActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Notificaciones"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez mi solución no se ajusta a tu código pero podría ser de ayuda para ti, yo logre hacerlo de la siguiente manera, solo agrega en tu AndroidManifest:

```
     <meta-data
             android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon            
android:resource="@drawable/ic_bell" />
```

Crea una nueva actividad, la cuál va ser tu actividad a lanzarse por default, por ejemplo para mi es `PushNotificationsActivity.java` (se va abrir al dar clic sobre la push en la barra de notificaciones):

```
....

      <activity
                android:name=".firebase.notifications.PushNotificationsActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
...
```

Ahora bien, veo que estas guardando en una base de datos en caso de ser una push de tipo "Frase", aquí te dejo algo similar, guardo la push en mi DB para porteriormente mostrarla en CardView, pero te dejo la parte en la que se reciben los datos de la push, en tu `PushNotificationsActivity.java`

```
.....
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_notifications));

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
           /// getIntent().getExtras().keySet() --------AQUI OBTIENES LA PUSH Y PUEDES HACER LO QUE NECESITES, EN MI CASO ALMACENO MI PUSH EN LA BASE DE DATOS--------
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()){
                if (key.equals("idPush")){
                    OperacionesDB.Pushs.setPush(new Push(Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("idPush")),
                            getIntent().getExtras().getString("titulo"), getIntent().getExtras().getString("descripcion"),
                            getIntent().getExtras().getString("fecha"), getIntent().getExtras().getString("hora"),
                            Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("tipo")), getIntent().getExtras().getString("estadoVisto"),
                            Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("fkIdUserPush"))));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
.....
```